# Laravel - User Profile Creation

Tags: php, laravel

In the system I'm creating, a User can choose whether their account would be for a 'Patient' or a 'Doctor' upon creation. A profile should then be created with the account depending on the user type.

Everything was working well until I modified the public function profile() on my User model.

From:

```
public function profile() { 
    return $this->hasOne(PatientProfile::class); 
}
```

To:

```
public function profile() { 
    if($this->hasRole('patient')) { 
        return $this->hasOne(PatientProfile::class); 
} 
    elseif($this->hasRole('doctor')) { 
        return $this->hasOne(DoctorProfile::class); } 
}
```

Since there are different fields for a Patient and a Doctor. I started getting an error "Call to a member function create() on null" when creating an account, and I believe it's because of $this->hasRole not working as intended.

What should I use in my User model to get a newly registered account's Role?

Comment: There is no method named hasRole

Comment: I think it's included with the Laratrust package that I'm using. Are there any alternative methods I can use?

Comment: Consider what your profile function will return if the User does not have one of the two roles you’re checking for.